# Cannot add constraint to table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to add a constraint to `competition` table, so I did:

```
ALTER TABLE `competition`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_categories_competition_category_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`category`)
REFERENCES `swp`.`competition_categories` (`id`);
```

the table `competition_categories` have the following design:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `swp`.`competition_categories` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

when I execute the query above, I get:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`swp`.`#sql-49a_c6`, CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_categories_competition_category_id` FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `competition_categories` (`id`))

Comment: Do you have data in the table already which doesnt fulfill the constraint?

Comment: yes the table have data

Answer (score 1):

The error message means a foreign key value does not exist in the reference table

Comment: The problem's that the value exist

Comment: Check the tables if there are no deleted or (non-existing) data that you are trying to insert into your table from the other table .